# C - Program fails to get file descriptor only when running with GDB

Tags: c, linux

I'm not an expert C programmer. I'm having trouble debugging a program using GDB. (The bug I am trying to fix is unrelated to the problem I am asking about here.) My problem is that the program runs fine when I run the binary directly from a shell, but the program crashes when I run it using GDB.

Here is some information about the program which may be useful: it is a 20+ year old piece of database software, originally written for Solaris (I think) but since ported to Linux, which is setuid (but not to root, thank god).

The program crashes in GDB when trying to open a file for writing. Using GDB, I was able to determine that crash occurs because the following system call fails:

```
fd = open(path, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0644);
```

For clarification: `path` is the path to a lockfile which *should not* exist. If the lock file exists, then the program shuts down cleanly before it even reaches this system call.

I do not understand why this system call would fail, since 1) The user this program runs as has rwx permissions on the directory containing `path` (I have verified this by examining the value of the variable stored in `path`), and 2) the program successfully opens the file for writing when I am not using GDB to debug it.

Are there any reasons why I cannot

Comment: what is errno when open() fails?

Comment: Is there any chance this is a race condition?  Could another thread be creating the lock file?

Comment: Is the path absolute or relative?

Comment: Are you stepping into the open system call?

Comment: @ensc - the return value is `-1`. Do you know what that signifies?  http://codewiki.wikidot.com/c:system-calls:open isn't helpful in that regard. @steveha - that's a good suggestion, but I paused the program at the line where it attempts to open the file, and that file doesn't exist.

Comment: put `perror("open problem") after the open to get the description of what -1 is indicating.

Comment: @Floris - Absolute paths.

Comment: @JamilSeaidoun - what do you mean? In what context? @Duck - Could you please be more specific? Do I put this in the source code and recompile? And what is `open problem`?

Comment: Is path a command line argument, or read in from one? If yes, and there is more than one, make sure to use proper gdb command line syntax (e.g., on gdb command line, set args $(printf "<arg1> <arg2> ...") or something like this; then run).

Comment: `-1` is the common return code indicating an error. For details, you have to read `errno`

Comment: @gnometorule - good idea, but no, the pathname is generated automagically at runtime. There are no command line arguments passed to this program.

Comment: if ((fd = open(path, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0644)) == -1)     {perror("open problem"); exit(1);}  Just prints the error description corresponding to errno and exits.

Comment: Thanks Duck. However, when I did that and recompiled, I got a segfault at the `perror` line. :( Here's the output: `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000003377663a13 in perror_internal () from /lib64/libc.so.6`

Comment: `path` is probably a bad pointer value, and the program merely works by luck (whether that's "good luck" or "bad luck" depends on your point of view).  Running under gdb disturbs the addressing enough to make it fail instead.

Comment: open is a kernel system call, stepping into it (i.e going into the function to debug line by line) won't work and so depending on GDB installed it's possible it will not let you continue (some will just not enter and skip to the next line)

Comment: @torek - I'm confused by what you're saying. `path` is a null-terminated `char*` type, and when I examine it using `print path` in GDB, it prints a valid pathname.

Comment: @JamilSeaidoun I see what you're saying now. No, I'm definitely not stepping into `open()` while debugging.

Comment: It's hard to tell without more information, but if gdb can print it correctly, maybe it's not bad after all.

Comment: @torek - just so we're on the same page- this is the output from `print path` in gdb: `$2 = "/usr/local/addhost/lib/dblocks/3460", '\000' <repeats 4061 times>`. That directory exists, and it looks like a valid `char*` to me, so I think it's fine.

Comment: Ah, OK, it's actually an array then.  So that is not (by itself at least) the problem.

Comment: @torek - whew. Sorry for any confusion, as I said I'm not much of a C programmer, so a `char*` and a `char[]` sometimes look similar to me :)

Comment: Oh, of course: if the program runs setuid (to some user), then, when run under gdb it does *not* run setuid.  You'll have to run gdb as that user.

Comment: @torek - why wouldn't it setuid when run with gdb?

Comment: If you stop the program with the debugger and alter its internal data and then resume it, you can defeat the program's internal security measures.  So, to sidestep this, the kernel disables setuid-ness whenever a process is run with debug enabled.  (Consider a trivial example, a game with a "high scores" file.  You run the game under the debugger, die immediately, but stop at the "register score" function.  You change your score to ONE BILLION POINTS!!! and resume.)

Comment: Check `ulimit -n`, I think that since you're running it in GDB the max number of files that you can have open is shared between the processes.

Comment: @torek - that was the problem, thanks. I `sudo su -`ed to the user that this program runs as, and now GDB works. add it as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key turns out to be this bit:

> ... is setuid (but not to root, thank god).

When you run a program under (any) debugger (using any of the stop-and-inspect/modify program facilities), the kernel disables setuid-ness, even for non-root setuid.

If you think about this a bit it makes sense.  Consider a game that keeps a "high scores" file, and uses "setuid games" to do this, with:

```
fd = open(GAME_SCORE_FILE, open_mode, file_mode);
score_data = read_scores(fd);
/* set breakpoint here or so */
if (check_for_new_high_score(current_score, score_data)) {
    printf("congratulations, you've entered the High Scores records!\n");
    save_scores(fd, score_data);
}
close(fd);
```

Access to the "high scores" file is protected by file permissions: only the "games" user can write to it.

If you run the game under a debugger, though, you can set a breakpoint at the marked line, and set the current_score data to some super-high value and then resume the program.

To avoid allowing debuggers to corrupt the internal data of setuid programs, the kernel simply disables setuid-ness when running code with debug facilities enabled.  If you can `su` (or `sudo` or whatever) to the user, indicating that you have permission regardless of any debugging, you can then run gdb itself as that user, so that the program runs as the user it "would have" setuid-ed to.

Comment: Unfortunately, this means I need to find a new method for debugging my problem, as the bug I am trying to investigate using GDB is something that only occurs for one user of the program, so it's important that I run this program as her user. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Figures. :-)  Setuid is a pain, it's no wonder they dropped the whole concept from Plan 9 (client/server with proper authentication is a much simpler model).  The first thing to look at with her settings is any special environmental setups, such as different env variables, user limits (`ulimit` output), and sometimes even weird stuff like tty modes.

Comment: I think it may be her Windows PuTTY client. She's having weird keybinding issues. Nobody (including myself) in a Linux environment can replicate the problem, and I can't replicate it when I `su -` to her either. I was hoping to run GDB as her from her Windows box and examine the value of the variables which store her keystrokes, but alas, I don't think that approach will work.

Comment: @jayhendren, at this point your best bet is to sprinkle logging statements into the code, and let her run it and see what you get in the log output. When all else fails, debug with `printf()`.

Comment: I'm thinking I can get gdb to work by attaching to somebody else's running instance of this program. First, she'll fire up the program, then I'll `su` and `gdb <program name> -p <pid>`. I've tried it a bit but I can't get it to work right. GDB keeps claiming `ptrace: Operation not permitted.` after it attaches to the process.

Comment: fixed it. `sudo gdb <program name> -p <pid>` did it. Hooray!